# How to only detect if is an iOS devices and redirect?

Tags: iphone, flash, redirect, detect

I'm currently using this to detect if the visitors have flash installed or not and if not right away I'm assuming they are iPhone users but then now it seems it doesn't always work like I wish to because sometime they being redirect to the version of flash of my site and sometime the person who got flash installed also redirect to an iPhone version of my site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
     <script src="http://www.featureblend.com/flash_detect_1-0-4/flash_detect.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(!FlashDetect.installed){
        window.location = "?flash=false";       
    }else{
        window.location = "?flash=true";
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

the thing is how would I detect if they are iPhone/iPad/iPod/AppleTV something like that and redirect them to the flash=false URL and if they are non of the above will be redirect to flash=true?

I have tried to find but really can't find the exact what I'm looking for

Thank you and Merry X'Mas to all of you.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: If you are using PHP you can also use .htaccess to do that

Comment: is there any source of information I can take a look? really my course will start next semester for PHP but this is for my website and I really want to know so I can solve this problem//// sorry to interrupt you

Comment: I'll add that code to my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials about how to achieve this. You can start from here:
http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm

Briefly, you can simply look for the strings "iphone", "ipod", "ipad" etc... into the user agent string with a code similar to this:

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("ipod") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("ipad") > -1 ||
    uagent.search("appletv") > -1) {
   window.location = "?flash=false";       
} else {
   window.location = "?flash=true";
}
```

Merry Christmas to you too :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer so I use || or && condition to achieve for the rest of the devices?

Comment: Check my updated answer: they are exclusive conditions, if a device is an ipod then it can't also be an ipad or an iphone, so you will have to use ||.

Comment: Thanks this simply gives me the best solution for my visitors :D Happy Holiday!

Answer (score 3):

Try using something similar to

```
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_iphone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1);
if (is_iphone) { conditional code goes here }
```

**Update**: You can also redirect user by using the .htaccess file. This htaccess rule will check if the user is using iPhone and if yes then redirect to the subdomain 'iphone'

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteRule .* http://iphone.mydomain.com/ [R]
```

If you don't know how to use .htaccess files [here](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/htaccess-tips/) is a blog post that I had written earlier about it.

To add more devices add code similar to
JavaScript:

```
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_iphone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1);
var is_ipad = ((agent.indexOf('ipad')!=-1);
if (is_iphone || ipad) { conditional code goes here }
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad
RewriteRule .* http://ios.mydomain.com/ [R]
```

Comment: No you will have to check each type of device

Comment: Thanks that is very good information but just one last question with the both code you provide how can I add more condition for other devices?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to dynamically load javascript files only when the user was on IOS/safari, this is what I came up with:

```
<script>
    //include jquery when mobile.
    var isIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
    if(isIOS){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type='text/javascript';
        script.src = 'js/jquery.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the User-Agent string to identify the device the user is using and redirect accordingly. You will have to check of all different devices, iphone, ipad,, ipod, appletv, etc